# Caps lock indicator not synced

Tags: keyboard, indicator

I have a laptop which I hook up to an external display when I'm at home. I also connected an external keyboard and mouse which makes it more comfortable for me.

I have noticed that pressing caps lock on the external keyboard does not light up the capslock indicator of the laptop keyboard (and vice versa).

When googling, I came across the **setleds** function, but when I type it into a console all I get is this:

```
KDGKBLED: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error reading current flags setting. Maybe you are not on the console?
```

Any idea if I can get this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug and there is nothing that you can do for the moment to fix it (I have the same issue):

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/830063
- http://marc.info/?l=linux-input&m=135047785511198&w=2
- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21266

Also, `setleds` it's working only in console mode (one among tty1-tty6), but this will not solve the problem. Check `man setleds` to see what it's purpose is (there is also one example there).

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to accept this problem won't go away then. Is there any sign that or information saying that this will be fixed in the future?

Comment: @MichaelAquilina Who knows? Right now you can only wait for bug to be fixed, or if you have the necessary resources (I don't have them) you can try to fix it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F5 or F6 to change current tty

Then login in a new tty and use it

```
setleds -caps
```